# How could I disable some configs if I'm loading from IEx?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have tons of `quantum` jobs that generates log trash inside my `iex`. From my `phoenix` app:

```
# config/dev.exs
config :quantum, MyApp,
  cron: [
    # Tons of jobs here
  ]
```

So, I want this part to be included in configs only from the phoenix.server, but not from IEx. How could I do that?

Comment: Does this work for you: `if IEx.started? do; config :quantum, MyApp, cron: [ # Tons of jobs here ]; end`?

Comment: Yeah, but with `unless`. Could you post the answer, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if `iex` is running using `IEx.started?/0`. If you put this in `unless` and wrap the `config` call inside it, the config will only be added if `iex` is not running:

```
# config/dev.exs
unless IEx.started? do
  config :quantum, MyApp,
    cron: [
      # Tons of jobs here
    ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, dear Dogbert!

Comment: Worth noting that in production `IEx.started?` returns false in prod.exs + runtime.exs when started via `iex -S mix`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on elixir 1.15. In my case, `IEx.started?` returns `false` in the `runtime.exs` and `prod.exs` file. My assumption is this is because these files are executed before whatever state `IEx.started?` relies upon is updated.

In my case, the way to disable quantum in IEx on prod was to create `.iex.exs` file and remove the scheduler process:

```
Supervisor.terminate_child(App.Supervisor, App.Scheduler)
Supervisor.delete_child(App.Supervisor, App.Scheduler)
```